# Is there a guideline for when to use != instead of (!condition) in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a rule or guideline for when to use `!=` instead of `(!condition)` when checking if a condition is true or false?

For instance, I have some pages that check if TLS is enabled before returning anything:

`if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') { exit; }`

But I could also write it like this:

`if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') { exit; }`

For some statements it seems cleanest to use the latter, for instance:

`if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }`

... is shorter than the equivalent:

`if (isset($_SESSION) == false) { session_start(); }`

Is there a standard or guideline for writing these statements, or is it just preference?

Note: I understand the difference between `==` and `===`, I just want to make sure my code is as clear and concise as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') { exit; }
```

! has higher precedence than ===, so this evaluates to:

```
if ((!$x) === 'on') { ... }
```

In this case, !$x will cast $x to boolean, then invert it. So, if $x has anything at all in it, you'll end up with:

```
if (false === 'on') { ... }
```

And this will never match for any value of $x.

Answer (score 2):

I would contest that

```
if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') { exit; }
```

is less indicative and, therefore, less readable than the first variant.

Any time you have something like simply

```
if ($var)
```

or

```
if (!$var)
```

what you're doing is coercing the passed value to their truthy/falsy value. So this is not the same thing as:

```
if ($var === 'on')
```

which is testing against a specific comparison (not its truthy/falsy).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's up to you really, but I try to make things sound as close to English as possible.

Would you say:

```
If switch is not on then…
```

or

```
If not switch is on then…
```

I'd personally say the top one, so would write the code to follow that.

For the second style one, if the thing returns a boolean (i.e. true or false), I never compare it to true or false, unless you have to with something like `strpos`.

Again, thinking of English:

```
If not is set variable…
```

or

```
If is set variable is false…
```

Personally, the top sounds better, though of course both aren't right in English.

This logic also helps to name variables and functions, so I'd consider it worth thinking about.

Comment: I hadn't thought to evaluate my statements in plain English, it makes plenty of sense to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The not `!` operator inverts a statement. In a condition, it is used to check if a particular value would evaluate to `false`. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), the following values would evaluate to false:

- The boolean `FALSE`
- The integer `0` and the float `0.0`
- An empty string *and* a string containing a zero (`"0"`)
- An empty array
- `NULL` and unset variables
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
- (PHP 4 only) an object with zero variables

Given this, you should use the not operator when you're checking if the variable is *falsy*.

For any other condition, you need to check the value explicitly.

Incidentally, `if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') { exit; }` and `if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') { exit; }` are quite different. The former checks if the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable does **not** have the value `on`. The latter on the other hand, *inverts* the value of `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and then compares it with `on` and returns true if they are equal.

So for example if `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is initially `"off"` (a non-zero string and therefore, `true`) `!$_SERVER['HTTPS']` would return `false` and then compare it with `"on"`. Since `false` and `"on"` are not equal, your `if` condition will not be executed.

The `isset` function returns a boolean value, so it is perfectly all right to do `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` because this will check if `$_SESSION` is falsy or not (will execute the `if` statement if it is).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for the well thought out answer!